# DTO Reference Class not recorded, 'null' after create

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, dto

I have DTO class called RoomDetailDto as below

```
public class RoomDetailDto {

String ID;

@NotEmpty
String cd;

@NotEmpty
String name;

String dscp;


RoomCategoryDto roomCategoryDto;

//setter and getter
```

**roomCategoryDto** have reference to another DTO called RoomCategoryDto as below:

```
public class RoomCategoryDto {

String ID;

@NotEmpty
@Length(min = 0, max = 5)
String cd;

@NotEmpty
String name;

@NotEmpty
@NumberValue
String cost;

String dscp;

//setter and getter
```

this JSON I send to the server

> {
>       "cd":"dfs23",
>       "name":"df223",
>       "dscp":"sfdsfs",
>       "roomCategoryDto":{
>           "cd":"KLS2",
>           "name":"Kelas 2",
>           "cost":"200000",
>           "dscp":null,
>           "id":"7f554d7a-3c5d-4c15-921d-fa4b4c629e6c"
>       }
>   }

after send to server, that record successfully inserted but my **roomCategoryDto** is **'NULL'**

> {
>       "cd": "dfs23",
>       "name": "df223",
>       "dscp": "sfdsfs",
>       "roomCategoryDto": null,
>       "id": "ed22b38d-2bc3-4c80-b035-8936318c90c7"
>   }

anyone can advice?
Please find my controller as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateAction", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public RoomDetailDto update(@Validated @RequestBody RoomDetailDto data) throws ParseException, RecordNotFoundException, java.text.ParseException {
    logger.info("add");
    RoomDetailEntity add = roomDetailService.updateRoomDetail(convertToEntity(data));
    return convertToDto(add);

}
```

and my entity as below

```
@Entity(name = "RoomCategoryEntity") @Table(name = "t_room_category") public class RoomCategoryEntity implements Serializable {

public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
private String ID;

@Column(name = "cd")
private String cd;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "cost")
private String cost;

@Column(name = "dscp")
private String dscp;

@Column(name = "createDate")
private Date createDate;

@Column(name = "updateDate")
private Date updateDate;

@Column(name = "isDel")
private Date isDel; //setter and getter}
```

==================================================================

```
@Entity(name = "RoomDetailEntity") @Table(name = "t_room_details") public class RoomDetailEntity implements Serializable {
public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
private String ID;

@Column(name = "cd")
private String cd;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "dscp")
private String dscp;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "room_category_id", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private RoomCategoryEntity roomCategoryEntity;

@Column(name = "createDate")
private Date createDate;

@Column(name = "updateDate")
private Date updateDate;

@Column(name = "isDel")
private Date isDel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to change reference table to entity, and successfully inserted

```
public class RoomDetailDto {

String ID;

@NotEmpty
String cd;

@NotEmpty
String name;

String dscp;

// I change below line
RoomCategoryEntity roomCategoryEntity;
```

> [
>       {
>           "cd": "df23",
>           "name": "df23",
>           "dscp": "sfdsfs",
>           "roomCategoryEntity": {
>               "cd": "KLS2",
>               "name": "Kelas 2",
>               "cost": "200000",
>               "dscp": null,
>               "createDate": 1497535268000,
>               "updateDate": null,
>               "isDel": null,
>               "id": "7f554d7a-3c5d-4c15-921d-fa4b4c629e6c"
>           },
>           "id": "02c28356-9783-46a7-8ac5-9e00497d9be2"
>       }
>   ]